# Catch ios::failure keeps looping

Tags: c++

The code below should check every input once and display "Not a number" whenever the input is not a number.

```
int input;
while (1 == 1){
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    try{
        cin.exceptions(istream::failbit);
        cin >> input;
    }catch(ios::failure){
        cout << "Not a number\n";
        input = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the catch is called (when it is not a number) **it displays "Invalid number" endlessly** like if the while() loop was executed several times but without asking for any new input.

Comment: You really should catch by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(true)` or `while(1)` [or `for(;;)`] are customary ways to make a "forever loop".

You need to "clean up" the input that isn't acceptable within the `cin` stream. 
The typical approach is to call `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');` which will ignore all input  until the next newline [up to 1000 characters - you can choose a bigger number, but usually a 1000 is "enough to get to a newline].

You will almost certainly also (thanks Potatoswatter) need to call `cin.clear();` on the input, to remove the `failed` state, so that next input can succeed. [And `cin.ignore()` is further input, so it needs to go before that - just to be clear].

Comment: or `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: Yeah, but that's very tedious to remember... ;)

Comment: @Rov You should call `clear()` before you call [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Answer (score 1):

Though you failed to extract characters from the stream into an `int`, those characters remain in the stream so that you can attempt to extract them as something else, instead.

To skip them entirely, run `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` inside your `catch` block.

Then, whatever the user enters *next* will be the first thing in the stream. And perhaps that'll be a number, so your next attempt to extract into an `int` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah. Your try-catch statement is inside the loop. So you try something, it fails and throws an exception, then you catch the exception, and you never exit or return from the loop so you do the same thing all over again.

But since your input wasn't processed the first time (throwing an exception **instead**), it's not going to be processed the second time, or the third time, or any time.

To advance, handle the exception by ignoring the input until the next space:

```
int input;
while (1 == 1){
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    try{
        cin.exceptions(istream::failbit);
        cin >> input;
    }catch(ios::failure){
        cout << "Not a number\n";
        input = 0;
        //the line below ignores all characters in cin until the space (' ')
        //(up to 256 characters are ignored, make this number as large as necessary
        cin.ignore(256, ' ');  
    }
}
```

By the way, as a general rule: exceptions should be for something that is truly exceptional, particularly since there is overhead for handling the exception. There is debate about [whether invalid user input is exceptional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614945/is-invalid-user-input-a-valid-reason-for-throwing-an-exception).

As an alternative, you can make a much more compact, equally correct loop without exceptions like the following:

```
int input;
while (true){  //outer while loop that repeats forever. Same as "while(1 == 1)"
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    //The following loop just keeps repeating until a valid value is entered.
    //The condition (cin >> input) is false if e.g. the value is a character,
    //or it is too long to fit inside an int.
    while(!(cin >> input)) { 
      cout << "Not a number" << endl;
      input = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, I just got 3 downvotes for this which were subsequently rescinded ... am I missing something?

Comment: You say nothing about why the stream isn't advancing past the bad input or how to fix the problem. The first version of your answer didn't even say anything about the input at all.

Comment: @Jerry cin.ignore until the next space. You can do it like so:
`cin.ignore(256, ' ');`

Comment: @user2357112 Fair enough, fixed now. I clicked post on the very first version accidentally ...