# Exceptions vs. Return Codes For User Input

Tags: php, exception, coding-style, return

[Some previous answers here for background reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614945/is-invalid-user-input-a-valid-reason-for-throwing-an-exception)

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function do_something_to_db($db_object, $param1, $param2){
    if (!isset($param1) || !isset($param2)){
        // Let user know that user-supplied arguments are incorrect.
    } else {
        $db_object->do_some_call($param1, $param2);
        if ($db_object->is_last_call_success()){
            $valuable_number = $db_object->get_last_call_result();
            // Success: let user know information from database call.
        } else {
            // Let user know that database call failed.
        }
    }
}
```

So for each of the three cases, I need to communicate:

- whether the function succeeded or failed
- if success, database data from call
- if fail, what the problem was

Is it clearer to express this with return codes and constants or use exceptions? Or is there some alternative that would be better? Please focus on readability and maintainability in your answers!

Comment: Personally, I always prefer exceptions... more control over where they're caught, and different exceptions can be thrown for different purposes; and strops() is a prime example of causing confusion among many devs by returning false or 0

Comment: Do you ever find that you litter your code with a lot of boilerplate exception code though? That's how my first attempt turned out.

Comment: No more than I'd do if I was testing for false or not false; I find using exceptions is normally far cleaner and easier to read

Comment: And because you can set both an error code and a (customised) message with an exception, you can pass a lot more information back up through to the calling methods; e.g. when reading a file, "invalid input at line x char y"... far more useful than a simple false status; and if you want to send more detailed information back via a status, it's a lot more code than simply `throw new Exception("invalid input at line x char y", 5)`... and with exceptions, you can also keep track of nested exceptions

Comment: And with exceptions, reference to the file/line/trace stack where the exception was thrown is also automatically available where it's caught for debugging purposes

Comment: If the call stack is deep and you aren't catching and re-throwing the exception, is there a good way to indicate that a function has the potential for throwing an exception?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I use @exception in my docblocks, nested up as far as necessary; but have to set that manually

Comment: So docblocks for exceptions... hm. (I considered that, but was wondering if there was anything conventional like the throws keyword in Java or the _privatefunction leading underscore in Python)

Comment: Sorry, yeah.... meant @throws